# Pre processor directive conio.h c++

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive, conio

As in C++ header files are used without .h extension like `<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>` but its not same in case of `<conio.h>`. Why we can't use `<conio>`

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard specifies which headers are part of the C++ standard library. In addition to C++-specific headers, it includes the headers specified by the C standard. You can use them with their C names (e.g., `#include <stdio.h>`), and they put their symbols into the global namespace. You can use them without the `.h` extension and a `c` on the front (e.g., `#include <cstdio>`), and they put their symbols into the namespace `std`.

But that's **only** for the headers from the C standard. `conio.h` is **not** part of the C standard, so the C++ standard doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

conio.h is a C header, thus (traditionally) C headers had the .h extension for the system headers. C++ standard headers are mainly without this .h extension. As you may know, many C headers (those from the standard library) have C++ counterparts (like  in C++ is )

Answer (score 0):

Because `conio.h` is a C header, not C++ specific.

Answer (score 0):

conio isn't part of the c++ standard, so you can't count on the compiler to know what it is. :(

In fact, i think it's usually only supported under windows.